# Avoid gulp running a task if file has not changed (multiple user)

Tags: git, gulp

I'm using gulp-changed to avoid running a task if the files didn't change.

The images in assets/images and the one in DEST/images are committed in the git repository.

The problem is when other peoples run the task for the first time it regenerate all images. The images has certainly a bit different because git mark theme as modified.

How can I avoid generating optimizing images **for every user* if the original image didn't change.

This is what I'm using it right now

```
// Optimize image and move them in the DEST folder
gulp.task('images', function () {
  return gulp.src(['assets/images/**'])
    // Take only files changed since the last time it was run
    .pipe(changed(DEST + '/images'))
    .pipe(imagemin({
      pngquant: true,
      progressive: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST + '/images'))
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It would make sense to see if the source images (assets/images/) have changed rather than checking the DEST versions.
Personally I've found gulp-change too slow and it's actually just quicker to run through them than have it check first. Obviously depends on when and where you are doing it, and how many images you have.

Comment: This is how changed works, comparing src and dest. See the doc https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-changed

Comment: Yep good point, I guess my brain doesn't work very well! If the images have been minified from the originals, won't the dest files always be different to the src ones?!

Comment: First, how I get it is change have different methode of comparison (hash, date).... but yes blurry for me too. I will try to find out more and come back here to answer this question!